# Parsing a protocol message from Go by Java

Tags: java, go, protocol-buffers

I write a server(Go)-client(Java) programe, and use protobuf for communication.
Define a proto file and share between server and client.
In server side:

- compile shared proto file into go by protoc
- serialize the object by proto.Marshal
- send it to client that make a request to its service

In client side:

- compile shared proto file into java by protoc
- get bytes is transferred via http
- deserialize the bytes into object.

Here i get following error:

> "com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length."

I confirmed http work fine and value of bytes received in client side are same to bytes send by server. Do you have same problem on this?

Here is proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";
package tutorial;

message Person {
    string name = 1;
    int32 id = 2; 
    string email = 3;

    enum PhoneType {
        MOBILE = 0;
        HOME = 1;
        WORK = 2;
    }

    message PhoneNumber {
        string number = 1;
        PhoneType type = 2;
    }

    repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}

message AddressBook {
    repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

In Go server side :

```
func TodoIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    p := &Person{
        Id:    1234,
        Name:  "John Doe",
        Email: "jdoe@example.com",
        Phones: []*Person_PhoneNumber{
            {Number: "555-4321", Type: Person_HOME},
        },
    }
    out, err := proto.Marshal(p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    w.Write(out)
}
```

In Java client side:

```
public class MainJavaAndGo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        long start = (new Date()).getTime();
        System.out.println("begin get");
        connect();

        System.out.println("end get");
        long time = (new Date()).getTime() - start;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void connect(){
    DefaultBHttpClientConnection connection = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
    HttpHost server = hostForString("localhost:8080");
    try {

        Socket socket = new Socket(server.getHostName(), server.getPort());
        connection.bind(socket);

        HttpCoreContext writeContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
        writeContext.setTargetHost(server);

        BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest httpRequest = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("GET",
                "/todos");

        HttpProcessor httpproc = makeHttpProcessor();
        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();
        httpexecutor.preProcess(httpRequest, httpproc, writeContext);
        HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(httpRequest, connection, writeContext);
        httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, writeContext);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        Addressbook.AddressBook addressBook = Addressbook.AddressBook.parseFrom(data);
        int foo = 0;
        foo++;


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            connection.shutdown();
        }catch (Exception ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public static  HttpHost hostForString(String hostStr) {
    String[] host = hostStr.split(":", 2);
    HttpHost httphost = new HttpHost(host[0], Integer.parseInt(host[1]));

    return httphost;
}

public static HttpProcessor makeHttpProcessor() {
    return HttpProcessorBuilder.create().add(new RequestContent()).add(new RequestTargetHost())
            .add(new RequestConnControl()).add(new RequestUserAgent("Test Protobuf/1.1"))
            .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();
}
}
```

I got InvalidProtocolBufferException

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:82)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.skipRawBytes(CodedInputStream.java:1200)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:578)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$Person.<init>(Addressbook.java:112)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$Person.<init>(Addressbook.java:77)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(Addressbook.java:1817)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(Addressbook.java:1812)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:816)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$AddressBook.<init>(Addressbook.java:1914)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$AddressBook.<init>(Addressbook.java:1871)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$AddressBook$1.parsePartialFrom(Addressbook.java:2571)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$AddressBook$1.parsePartialFrom(Addressbook.java:2566)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:163)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:197)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:209)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:214)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    at com.auth0.protobuf.Addressbook$AddressBook.parseFrom(Addressbook.java:2065)
    at com.auth0.MainJavaAndGo.connect(MainJavaAndGo.java:78)
    at com.auth0.MainJavaAndGo.main(MainJavaAndGo.java:35)
```

Comment: What does your socket on the Java side look like?  It sounds like you are only getting a partial message back.

Comment: on the Java side, i request service by HttpRequestExecutor
HttpHost server = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
            Socket socket = new Socket(server.getHostName(), server.getPort());
            connection.bind(socket);

Comment: At what point are you reading from the socket?  Can you edit your original post with that so it's formatted properly?

Comment: thank you for your comment. i've just post full version of java client side
i get bytes from server via HttpResponse by httpexecutor.execute. It's like response from a request to restful service.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all
I found answer from all your comment.
My serialize and deserialize structure is different.
I edited to
    Addressbook.Person person = Addressbook.Person.parseFrom(data);
and then it work.